# DisplayFormat ApplyFormatInEditMode Not Working as Expected - .NET Core Razor Pages EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Create, Delete, Details, Edit, and Index views have been generated using add new scaffolded item "Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD)". Details, Edit, and Index views do show the currency formatting, however Create does not. How can I display currency formatting on the Create view, and the edit view upon editing?

**LoanEstimate.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LoanCalculator.Models
{
    [ModelMetadataType(typeof(LoanEstimateMetadata))]
    public partial class LoanEstimate
    {

    }
    public class LoanEstimateMetadata
    {
        [DisplayName("Annual Taxes")]
        [DataType(dataType: DataType.Currency)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public decimal AnnualTaxes { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:p}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="LoanEstimate.AnnualTaxes" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="LoanEstimate.AnnualTaxes" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="LoanEstimate.AnnualTaxes" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

**Create Page Problem: Currency Format not applied**

[image: Create Page]

**Edit page Problem: Currency format is applied initially, but when I edit it is removed**
Initial Page load
[image]
After edit
[image]

I have the same problem for the percentage data format string as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the input with currency is a client side behavior but DisplayFormat is a server side behavior.So you could render the decimal with correct format but could not edit with the currency.A common way is to use jquery.

I suggest you can use `autoNumeric.js` like below:

```
<input asp-for="LoanEstimate.AnnualTaxesDisplayOnly" class="form-control" />
<script>
    var autoNumericInstance = new AutoNumeric("input[id='LoanEstimate_AnnualTaxesDisplayOnly']").northAmerican();
    $("input[id='LoanEstimate_AnnualTaxesDisplayOnly']").on('keyup', function () {
        $("input[id='LoanEstimate_AnnualTaxes']").val(autoNumericInstance.getNumericString());
    }); 
</script>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works, but introduces another hurdle to get through. Upon entering a value that is formatted with the currency symbol via the js, I get a validation message "The field Annual Taxes must be a number". What is your suggestion on how to address that?

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the following concept that resolves the hurdle and I will mark it as the answer: var autoNumericInstance = new AutoNumeric("input[id='LoanEstimate_AnnualTaxesDisplayOnly']").northAmerican();
            $("input[id='LoanEstimate_AnnualTaxesDisplayOnly']").on('keyup', function () {
                $("input[id='LoanEstimate_AnnualTaxes']").val(autoNumericInstance.getNumericString());
            });                 <input asp-for="LoanEstimate.AnnualTaxesDisplayOnly" class="form-control" />

Comment: Hi @MaxPowers,I have updated the answer.Please check. :)